# How Can I Change The Background Color of A List View Row Element's Press State in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I know how to change the background color of a list row element in SwiftUI using `.listRowBackground(Color.red)` for example. But when I do this the row no longer changes color when you press it. Note I do not mean the active row... I mean when your finger is pressing down on the row I want it to change color as visual feedback. Any suggestions on how I can retain the press state background color? Or even better how can I customize that press color?

Here's the code I'm playing with:

```swift
List {
    ForEach((viewModel.bookmarks )!, id: \.id) { bookmark in
        Button(action: {onTap(bookmark)}, label: {
            BookmarkCell(label: bookmark.trackName,
                         createAt: bookmark.date.bookmarkFormat(),
                         savePosition: bookmark.position.format(formatType: FormatType.hhmmss),
                         note: bookmark.note)
        }).listRowBackground(Color.red) // for testing
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get this working using `listRowInsets` and a state variable that changes on a `longPressGesture`. It's hacky and I dont want to post it as an answer because I am not sure if its what apple intends us to do with List rows and their insets.

Comment: @yonodactyl Thanks for this. Honestly no judgment at all... SwiftUI seems to require hacks more frequently than I'd like. If Apple intended something else they sure don't make it obvious.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you want the row to change color when pressed and then keep that color until another roe is pressed?

Comment: since on each row you seems only have abutton, you can use `ScrollView { LazyVStack {` instead of List, and then you don't have to look for any implicit behaviors of the list

Comment: @MacUserT no... I only want it to change color just while the users finger is pressing down on that row. This works as expected if you don't set a row background color, but as soon as you do that behavour goes away for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this. It's super ugly, but apple seems to have left me with no choice. Here's how I solved it:

```swift
struct MyComponent: View {
    
    // ... other vars
    @State var isPressed: [Int: Bool] = [:]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach((viewModel.bookmarks )!, id: \.id) { bookmark in
                Button(action: {onTap(bookmark)}, label: {
                    BookmarkCell(label: bookmark.trackName,
                                 createAt: bookmark.date.bookmarkFormat(),
                                 savePosition: bookmark.position.format(formatType: FormatType.hhmmss),
                                 note: bookmark.note)
                })
                // we get notified whenever a tap is happening using this callback
                // this definetly feels like a hack, but we are kinda left with no choice in this context. 
                .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity, pressing: { pressing in
                    isPressed[bookmark.id] = pressing
                }, perform: {})
                .listRowBackground(isPressed[bookmark.id] ?? false ? Color.white : Color.red) // for testing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else out too.

**Update: I found another solution that seems to work better**
This other solution is kind of equally hacky, but works better because it doesn't "swallow" the press events, where as the long press gesture does, which makes swipe actions and others not usable.

First we need to make a button style. This is because button styles
have a press state listener which allows you to change the style of the button on a press event. This is great! But unfortunately we cannot use this the straightforward way that typically you can, because `listRowBackground` is what we have to set to change our list row style, and for whatever reason this does nothing in the Button Style context. So we have to settle for the using the button style as a press event listener

```swift
struct PressableButtonStyle: SwiftUI.ButtonStyle {
    var onPress: (Bool) -> Void
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .onChange(of: configuration.isPressed) { newValue in
                onPress(newValue)
            }
    }
}
```

Then in our MyComponent code we just update our state in the same way as above, but without the `onLongPressGesture`

```swift
struct MyComponent: View {

    // ... other vars
    @State var isPressed: [Int: Bool] = [:]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach((viewModel.bookmarks )!, id: \.id) { bookmark in
                Button(action: {onTap(bookmark)}, label: {
                    BookmarkCell(label: bookmark.trackName,
                                 createAt: bookmark.date.bookmarkFormat(),
                                 savePosition: bookmark.position.format(formatType: FormatType.hhmmss),
                                 note: bookmark.note)
                })
                // we get notified whenever a tap is happening using this callback

                .buttonStyle(PressableButtonStyle(onPress: { isPressed in
                    isBookmarkPressed[bookmark.id] = isPressed
                }))
                .listRowBackground(isPressed[bookmark.id] ?? false ? Color.white : Color.red) // for testing
            }
        }
    }
}
```